# SQL Query - Convert data values into attributes into antother table.

Tags: sql

I am building a report and I am stuck formulating a query. I am bringing the following data from multiple tables after a lot of joins.

```
ID        TYPE    RATING
-----     ----    ------
ID_R1     A       1
ID_R1     B       3
ID_R2     A       2
ID_R2     B       1
ID_R3     A       4
ID_R3     B       4
ID_R4     A       2
ID_R4     B       3
ID_R5     A       2
ID_R5     B       3
```

What actually is happening is that `Every ID will have a Rating for Type A & B` so what I need to do is transform the above into the following

```
ID       Type_A_Rating    Type_B_Rating
-----    -------------    -------------
ID_R1    1                3
ID_R2    3                1
ID_R3    4                4
ID_R4    2                3
ID_R5    2                3
```

I have think group by and different techniques but so far I am unable to come up with a solution. Need help F1! F1!

p.s just for the record my end game is getting the count of (A,B) combinations

```
Type_A_Rating    Type_B_Rating    Count
-------------    -------------    -----
1                1                0
1                2                0
1                3                1
1                4                0
2                1                0
2                2                0
2                3                2
2                4                0
3                1                1
3                2                0
3                3                0
3                4                0
4                1                0
4                2                0
4                3                0
4                4                1
```

From this you can see that a simple `GROUP BY` with any form `AND` `OR` conditions doesn't suffice until I get the data as mentioned. I could use two intermediate/temp tables, in one get Type_A_Rating with ID and then in second Type_B_Rating with ID and then in another combine both but isn't there a better way.

Comment: none actually, I am working on SAS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work as SQL engine agnostic solution (provided that there is exactly one row with type A for each ID and one row with type B for each ID):

```
select
  TA.ID,
  TA.RATING as Type_A_Rating,
  TB.RATING as Type_B_Rating
from
(select ID, RATING
 from T where TYPE = 'A') as TA
inner join
(select ID, RATING
  from T where TYPE = 'B') as TB
on TA.ID = TB.ID
```

Related SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e6fd9/2

Alternative (simpler) solution:

```
select
  ID,
  sum(case when TYPE = 'A' then RATING else 0 end) as Type_A_Rating,
  sum(case when TYPE = 'B' then RATING else 0 end) as Type_B_Rating
from
  T
group by
  ID
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e6fd9/3

EDIT:

The above is correct but both can be simplified a bit:

```
select TA.ID, TA.RATING as Type_A_Rating, TB.RATING as Type_B_Rating
from T TA join
     T TB
     on TA.ID = TB.ID AND A.type = 'A' and B.type = 'B';
```

And (because I prefer `NULL` when there are no matches:

```
select ID,
       max(case when TYPE = 'A' then RATING end) as Type_A_Rating,
       max(case when TYPE = 'B' then RATING end) as Type_B_Rating
from T
group by ID
```